# How to use DatePicker in Android Preferences

Tags: java, android, xml

I know DatePicker isn't supported in the preferences, but I wanted to use it in my PreferencesActivity. I want the user to pick a date and that date is saved in YYYYMMDD format, and then if the user wants to edit the date, it will show the previous date that was set.

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find a good example, can someone please show me in simple steps how to perform this?

Comment: Here is a `DialogPreference` that uses a `TimePicker` that you might be able to adapt: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/blob/master/19-Alarm/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial/TimePreference.java

Answer (score 0):

To write a date and read a date object..you have to convert it into long..as for example

```
   //To Write a date 

   Date d=new Date();
   SharedPreferences preferences1  = getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", 0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor1  = preferences1.edit();
   editor1.putLong("keyValue",d.getTime());

   //To read a date
   Long x=preferences1.getLong("keyValue", 0L);
   Date d=new Date(x);
```